# Do Google Analytics track both HTTPS and HTTP traffic?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a few Chrome plugins published on the Google webstore with analytics and I noticed today that the protocols for the URL different depending on what I happen to have copy pasted. Will Google Analytics detect visitors to these pages on both HTTP and HTTPS?

[image: Google analytics page]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: yes.
Long answer: it depends on which version of the tracking code you are using. Meaning that if you are using an older version (`urchin.js`), you need to copy/paste a different tracking code into your secure pages. (<del>Here is the man page: http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55483</del>)

Comment: Ah then it's fine, because you only supply the UA-XXXXXXX-X to the webstore and googles handles the code. Thanks!

Comment: (link is now a 404.)